# Replacing previous number in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add an effect that some websites now have i.e. coffees drank: and then number of coffees drank, gradually growing from 0 to N-1. This is my attempt, if I print i in the console in the first if statement , each number prints out. But, when in HTML it goes from 0-950 instantly with no numbers in between.

To sum make it up: I would like the number to increment on the page, each new number replacing its previous number.

```
for (i = 0; i < 950; i++) {
  if ($("#counter").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // body...
      $("#counter").append('<p id = "counter">' + i + '</p>');
    }, 2000);
    console.log(i);

  } else {
    $(".coffee-drank").append('<p id = "counter">' + i + '</p>');
  }

}
```

Comment: add timeout. its increasing as expected but to fast to see

Comment: I tried that already did the same thing =/ but just slower, went from 0 to 949, very slowly.

Comment: so what do you want ? it should replace previous number thats expected ?

Comment: yes that's expected

Comment: please cclarify. you expected number to go from 0 to 949 and it did. what else

Comment: it goes from 0-949, it doesn't do the inbetween numbers 1,2,3,4...948

Comment: it does in the console log, but not in the HTML page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149891/discussion-between-shubham-singla-and-james).

Comment: you need timeout to see number change, to print `1,2,3,4...` use append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your idea correctly, it can be done generally like this:

```js
var start = -1, end = 950;
var countUp = function func() {
            if(start >= end) return;
            var elem = document.getElementById("counter");
            elem.innerText = ++start;
            setTimeout(func, 25);
        }
countUp();
```

```html
count up to 950: 
<span id="counter">0</span>
```

**UPDATE**
In your case it might look like this (no need for a cycle at all):

```
var start = -1, end = 950;
var countUp = function func() {
        if(start >= end) {
        // the end is reached; start is equal to 950 now; do something useful and quit
        $(".coffee-drank").append('<p id = "counter">' + start +'</p>');
        return;
        }
        $("#counter").text(++start);
        setTimeout(func, 25);
    }

countUp();
```

Comment: It'd be useful to know why my current implementation does not work correctly ?

Comment: you need a timer. Without a timer the cycle will work out instantly - all the values from 0 to 950 will be passed in a moment.

Comment: I've edited with the timer I added, still does not work. For some reason I believe when it's entering the first if statement, it's constantly returning i as 950 rather than 1,2,3,4...

Comment: you dont need the outer cycle and if-statement based on length; Instead you have to start the whole thing by `setTimeout(countDown, 500);`

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. Although it is hard to say what should be done after the target number (950) is reached since we don't know the whole setup and context.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop with this:

```
var speed = 16; // Lower is faster
increase(0, 950);
function increase(i, max){
    if(i <= max){
        if ($("#counter").length) {
            $("#counter").html(i);
        } else {
            $(".coffee-drank").append('<p id = "counter">' + i + '</p>');
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            increase(++i, max);
        }, speed);
    }
}
```